# Vertical align colon with numbers

Tags: html, css

I would like to create something as follows:

[image]

I created the example (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvOPGE) with HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><span>30</span>days</li>
  <li><span>24</span>hours</li>
  <li><span>60</span>minutes</li>
</ul>
```

And the following CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;  
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 80px;
}

ul li span {
  font-size: 32px;
  display: block;
}
```

The problem is how to add ":" inline with the numbers 30, 24 and 60.

I do not need keep the `ul`/`li` markup. It just seemed logic ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make one `div` element inside `li` for its content and then use `:after` pseudo-element for `:` between elements. Also you could take text out of normal flow with `position: absolute` so that `:` is in line with `numbers`.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
ul li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
ul li > div {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}
ul li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: ':';
  font-size: 30px;
}
ul li span:first-child {
  font-size: 60px;
}
ul li span:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><div><span>30</span><span>days</span></div></li>
  <li><div><span>24</span><span>hours</span></div></li>
  <li><div><span>60</span><span>minutes</span></div></li>
</ul>
```

Or you could use your HTML structure and add `:after` pseudo-element on `span` elements.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;  
  display: flex;
}
ul li {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul li span {
  font-size: 60px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 40px;
}
ul li:not(:last-child) span:after {
  content: ":";
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: 40px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>30</span>days</li>
  <li><span>24</span>hours</li>
  <li><span>60</span>minutes</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the colons as `li` elements in between the other `li`s, making them inline-blocks, with the same font-size as the numbers and `vertical-align: top;`:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;  
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 80px;
}
.colon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 32px;
}
ul li span {
  font-size: 32px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>30</span>days</li>
  <li class="colon">:</li>
  <li><span>24</span>hours</li>
  <li class="colon">:</li>
  <li><span>60</span>minutes</li>
</ul>
```

If you want the colons further up, apply `position: relative` to their `li` containers and move them up using a negative `top` value:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;  
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 80px;
}
.colon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 32px;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
}
ul li span {
  font-size: 32px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>30</span>days</li>
  <li class="colon">:</li>
  <li><span>24</span>hours</li>
  <li class="colon">:</li>
  <li><span>60</span>minutes</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add `<span>`s with colons in between the `<li>` tags

```
<ul>
  <li><span>30</span>days</li>
  <span>:</span>
  <li><span>24</span>hours</li>
  <span>:</span>
  <li><span>60</span>minutes</li>
</ul>
```

and style the whole  with a [flexbox layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 12px;
}

ul > li {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 80px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

ul > span, ul > li > span {
   font-size:32px;
}
```

see it in action at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WzLqzO

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Johannes looks like it should work, but I thought I might provide an alternative using the `::after` selector:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;  
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 80px;
}
.colon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 32px;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
}
ul li span {
  font-size: 32px;
  display: block;
}

// here is the part that I added
li span::after {
  content: ":";
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
li:last-child span::after {
  content: "";
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtr_webdev/1q3zr4fs/)