# Vertical align colon on list of text

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm doing a website project, with using a Materialize Framework.

There is a line of text where i would like to align all of the colon vertically. this is the example of the text:

```
Project:Intimate House  
Location : Pulau Putri, Puri - West Jakarta - Indonesia  
Site Area : 160 sqm  
Building Area : 210 sqm  
Design Phase : 2016 
Construction Period : April 2016 - July 2017
```

and this is the result of the vertically aligned colon that i want

```
Project                : Intimate House  
Location               : Pulau Putri, Puri - West Jakarta - Indonesia  
Site Area              : 160 sqm  
Building Area          : 210 sqm  
Design Phase           : 2016 
Construction Period    : April 2016 - July 2017
```

Below is my code that i try to create(https://codepen.io/bukuchaga/pen/xJNdeq)
HTML:

```html
                    <h4><b>Intimate House</b><br></h4>
                    <ul>
                      <li><b>Project:</b>Intimate House</li>
                      <li><b>Location       :</b> Pulau Putri, Puri - West Jakarta - Indonesia</li>
                      <li><b>Site Area      :</b> 160 sqm</li>
                      <li><b>Building Area  :</b> 210 sqm</li>
                      <li><b>Design Phase   :</b> 2016</li>
                      <li><b>Construction Period :</b> April 2016 -  July 2017</li>
                    </ul>
```

Based on my research before, i found a question that maybe similar to my question.([Vertical align colon with numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49739092/vertical-align-colon-with-numbers))

**The problem is** after i tried to apply the answer, it's still not working on my code, rather it turns my line of text became out of place from how it should be and i have tried several others method and still not working.

Thank you before.

Comment: Hi @Kevin. Please reduce your code to a [MCVE]. There is a lot of irrelevant HTML and JavaScript in your question making difficult to see the elements that you are talking about.

Comment: @Turnip ok, thank you for notifying me. let me fix it first.

Comment: Also note that `p` elements cannot contain `ul`...it's invalid HTML.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994516/html-css-best-practice-for-preserving-white-space-on-certain-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest removing the colon from the HTML and using a `::after` pseudo element instead.

```css
.alignMe b {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10px; /* Ensures colon does not overlay the text */
}

.alignMe b::after {
  content: ":";
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="alignMe">
  <li><b>Project</b> Intimate House</li>
  <li><b>Location</b> Pulau Putri, Puri - West Jakarta - Indonesia</li>
  <li><b>Site Area</b> 160 sqm</li>
  <li><b>Building Area</b> 210 sqm</li>
  <li><b>Design Phase</b> 2016</li>
  <li><b>Construction Period</b> April 2016 - July 2017</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yes, i noticed it just a moment ago, that if i shouldn't put another colon if i put ::after pseudo element

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now it works better. i was thinking of using `inline-block` a while ago, but didn't know you can set the space using `width`, probably that's the reason why i don't found the solution.

Answer (score 6):

Move the colon to *after* the `b` and use CSS-Tables

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
}

li {
  display: table-row;
}

b {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><b>Project</b>: Intimate House</li>
  <li><b>Location</b>: Pulau Putri, Puri - West Jakarta - Indonesia</li>
  <li><b>Site Area</b>: 160 sqm</li>
  <li><b>Building Area</b>: 210 sqm</li>
  <li><b>Design Phase</b>: 2016</li>
  <li><b>Construction Period</b>: April 2016 - July 2017</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of feasible way is to set `min-width` to `<b>` tag and add a colon after it. Simple example:

```css
ul.info-list {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.info-list li b {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 144px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
ul.info-list li b:after {
  content: ":";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="info-list">
  <li><b>Project</b>Intimate House</li>
  <li><b>Location</b> Pulau Putri, Puri - West Jakarta - Indonesia</li>
  <li><b>Site Area</b> 160 sqm</li>
  <li><b>Building Area</b> 210 sqm</li>
  <li><b>Design Phase</b> 2016</li>
  <li><b>Construction Period</b> April 2016 -  July 2017</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i see, it's quite simple but good enough for the result that i want. let me try it first.